# How to format command line arguments correctly in StyleGan2 readme example

Tags: python, machine-learning, command-line, command-line-arguments, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to run the example code from the StyleGan2 github repo.  https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2
the problem is that the line they suggest you run in the command line is as follows:

```
python run_generator.py generate-images --network=gdrive:networks/stylegan2-ffhq-config-f.pkl \
  --seeds=6600-6625 --truncation-psi=0.5
```

When I copy pasted this code, it ran the two lines separately and crashed, probably because of a newline character.  When I get rid of the newline character and replace it with a space, it gives the following error:

```
run_generator.py: error: unrecognized arguments: \
```

What is going on here and how to I fix it?  What do backslashes do in command line arguments and why is it unrecognized?  Is the readme's example just broken?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete backslash before `seeds` argument. It is used to make multiline commands on Linux (and some other OS). In windows you should use `^` to make multiline command.